# SQL query to display Count of records based in range from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, count

I have two tables `Range` and `Employee`.

`Range` table consists of columns

```
minimum_salary, maximum salary, program
```

(Available programs for that salary like platinum and silver etc).

`Employee` table has columns

```
Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Salary
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKaXP.png

[image]

I want to write a SQL query in such a way that it gets the  count of employees who fall under the given salary range in range table, please refer screenshot for tables and result set.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You've named three versions of SQL - which one is it. Can you also please show what you ave tried so far otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: How are the endpoints of your ranges treated? (Included or excluded) For example, the salary range for program 'XYZ' is from $20,000 to $30,000. Is someone with salary exactly $20,000 eligible for this program? What about $30,000 salary? (If you anser "yes" to both, that is most likely wrong. If program 'ABC' has range $30,000 to $50,000, then somoene with salary exactly $30,000 qualifies for both programs, but someone with salary $29,999.99 or $30,000.01 doesn't; that can't be right)

Comment: Also - can the ranges be open-ended (such as, "all salaries below $20,000" or "all salaries above $60,000"), or do they all have non-`null` minimum salary and non-`null` maximum salary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on inequality conditions:

```
select r.program, count(e.emp_id) no_employees
from ranges r
left join employees e on e.salary between r.min_salary and r.max_salary
group by r.program
```

Comment: This assumes the ranges are inclusive at both ends. In real life that's very unlikely. I just asked the OP to clarify.

Comment: @mathguy: yes, I phrased it that way because that’s what OP’s sample data is showing...

Comment: Lol - OK, I see the ranges now (I never follow links in posts). Salary is probably an integer, so they can do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please, add a column into `Range` table that name `Emp_ID`. Because, it help to join two table. I mean need primary key & foreign key.

Query:

```
select COUNT(e.empID), r.program
FROM rangeTable AS r
INNER JOIN empTable AS e ON e.salary BETWEEN r.min_salary AND r.max_salary
GROUP BY r.program
```